# UIImagePickerController Select Image IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

My app run on landscape mode only.

I read about this and say UIImagePickerController load only portrait mode.

**How can rotate the app to pick image and return to landscape mode again.**

I have this code and crashes my app.

```
- (IBAction)LoadImage:(id)sender {


        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate=self;
        [picker setSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:Nil];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
  //.....
}
```

**I try this but not work...**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN your code

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [##self## dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
  //.....
}
```

### self##  should be replaced with ##picker## if you want to dismiss the picker

Answer (score 0):

You just have to navigate again to your current view it works for me